# Customizing the height of the social network button

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin, twitter-login

I want to add three social network login button Facebook,Twitter and Google plus in my android App.Good thing is I've add these all the buttons with the functionality but the problem I am facing is how to adjust the height of all these button with same height.I can add padding to adjust the height but I think this will not be the right way to do. If any had faced this issue before and had resolved it before please share with me.

Here is the code I've done so far
It looks that height issue is fixed but login texts doesn't appears appropriate.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/line_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/elevation"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/line_layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="info here" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_padding_lr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
            android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_padding_lr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how about fixed dp for height for all of them?

Comment: that is the reason why I asked this question. If there is the better way please share

Comment: if the parent view has a known height, then you can use weighting and let the layout set the height of your buttons based on the available space

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the fixed dp height, you can place different dimension in different value folders to support multiple devices